# Do I have to implement try/catch on my async funtion, even though then/catch is implemented in the promise itself

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have async function like below:

```
(async function(){
    const returnedPromise=await getUser(ID);
    doStuffToUser();
})();

getUser=(ID)=>{
    return Database.getUser(ID).then(res=>{
        // user received from database
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('err -> ',err) // error happend
    })
}

doStuffToUser=()=>{
    // Do something on the user got from database
}
```

Considering the fact that I have implemented then/catch inside the `getUser` function, do I have to implement try/catch inside `async` function.

I mean is the then/catch inside `getUser` function enough? Or should I also implement try/catch inside the async function.

Comment: What value would you want returned from `getUser` if the database call fails? It doesn't sound like the error is recoverable.

Comment: Enough - for what? You should implement it where you *need* it, where it makes sense, and still keeps your functions reusable. `getUser` failing by returning `undefined` (and logging an error in the background) does not look useful.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. Now I better understand.